# Angular dependent subscriptions using forkJoin with code block for modifying data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscription

I have a subscription that depends on the result of a previous subscription.
I am using forkJoin so I don't have to nest them:

```
this.service.service1().pipe(
    flatMap((res1) => this.service.service2(res1))
).subscribe((res2) => {
    // Do something with res2.
});
```

The issue is that I need to modify the data before I call subscription #2. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
this.service.service1().pipe(
    flatMap((res1) => {
      // Modify res1 data here.
      // Make 2nd Api Call
      this.service.service2(res1)
    })
).subscribe((res2) => {
    // Do something with res2.
});
```

Do I need a different operator/syntax to achieve this or am I able to modify this approach?

Comment: You could use `map` before `flatMap` to make it maybe more obvious but if you don't want to return `res1` I think what you're doing now is fine.

Comment: @martin The second block of code above is not possible how I currently have it. flatMap does not allow for the {}. It will throw a **Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not returning an observable from your flatMap, return this.service.service2(res1); would do the same as below.

```
this.service.service1().pipe(
    map(res1 => //modify resp1 here)
    flatMap((modifiedRes1) => this.service.service2(modifiedRes1)) // note the lack of brackets, this means we are returning the observable, your function returns void.
).subscribe((res2) => {
    // Do something with res2.
});
```

The difference between

```
(res1) => this.service.service2(res1)
```

and

```
(res1) => {
  this.service.service2(res1)
}
```

Is that the first function returns an observable, the second one returns void.

```
(res1) => this.service.service2(res1)
```

and

```
(res1) => {
  return this.service.service2(res1)
}
```

are equivalent. {} creates a block, that block needs a return statement if it is use in an arrow function.